# Genre restrictions

Tags: phrases, vocabulary, semantics

How to say correctly: 'law of the genre', 'rules of the genre' or 'genre principles'?

For example:

> — In your fashion magazine no suffering at all. There are no hungry children, old age people...
>   — It's a law of the genre. It is necessary either to accept or not to accept.

Comment: *law* ≠ *rule* ≠ *principle* ≠ *convention* -- use whichever is applicable and appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of these would be perfectly understandable and acceptable.

In the LitCrit racket, however, the preferred term would be ***convention*** of the genre. Such conventions do not operate like “rules” or “laws”, in that violating them does not disqualify the work from being read as an instance of the genre. On the contrary: the conventions exist *in order to be violated*. It is in departing from the conventions that the artist achieves his most striking, significant and delightful effects.

Answer (score 0):

These look like playing with set phrases or clichés:

- "law of the genre" is like "law of the jungle"
- "rules of the genre" is like "rules of the game"
- "genre principles" is like "general principles"

Doing this can surprise and amuse the reader, and done well can be a feature of good writing.